# Flash / ActionScript 3: reference loader Document Class from loaded Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a FLA (say Main.FLA) document class with a child MovieClip on the stage: into the child MovieClip I want to load other swf files: each of the files contains its own Document Class (every swf is a somewhat independet application, say quizzes and so on). For some reason I must use the MAIN document class to store data from the child swfs loaded into the main FLA. HOW do I reference the Main class? I can't find a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did something similar I used events.
I created a class:

```
   package {
   import flash.events.Event;

    public class QuestionAnsweredEvent extends Event {
        public static const QUESTION_ANSWERED:String = "QuestionAnswered";
        public var data:*;

        public function QuestionAnsweredEvent(type:String, data:*) {
            this.data = data;
            super(type, true);
        }

    }

}
```

Then In the child SWF I dispatch this event:

```
dispatchEvent(new QuestionAnsweredEvent(QuestionAnsweredEvent.QUESTION_ANSWERED, questionData));
```

In the Parent SWF I add a standard event listener but inside the function I'm able to grab the event.data property to store the sent data.

Hope that helps. I'm relatively new to this myself but it worked well in my project.

EDIT:
In your main class:

```
swfmovieclip.addEventListener(QuestionAnsweredEvent.QUESTION_ANSWERED,onAnswer);

private function onAnswer(e:QuestionAnsweredEvent):void { 
storingVar = e.data; //this can change depending on the type of object you send 
}
```

EDIT2:
This is how I load my SWF that dispatches the event containing data:

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("RegionalQuestions.swf"));

ldr.addEventListener(QuestionAnsweredEvent.QUESTION_ANSWERED, questionAnswered);
questionsSWF = ldr;
addChild(ldr);
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your fantastic reply. I don't know if I understood well: this QuestionAnsererdEvent is imported into the (secondary) loaded swf Document Class file. Then, when you must communicate with the Main class, you dispatch an event, the Main listens to it and it performs an action (store value or other). Am I right? And, if so, could you provide me with a basic example of Main class too?

Comment: I tried adding addEventListener to the constructor of my Main class but it did not work...   :-(

Comment: Yeah thats right you need to import the class into both SWFs.
In your main class:
swfmovieclip.addEventListener(QuestionAnsweredEvent.QUESTION_ANSWERED,onAnswer);

private function onAnswer(e:QuestionAnsweredEvent):void {
storingVar = e.data; //this can change depending on the type of object you send
}

Comment: I try and make you know very soon.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. I changed your swfmovieclip to my classContainer_mc (the clip where the swf is loaded). The method you post here is exactly the same I just added to my main, so no changes here. In the document class of the loaded swf movie I dispatch the event the way you suggested. Inside my onAnswer method I have a trace (trace("fired!")), but the program never reaches that line.

Comment: I've added another edit above that shows how I load my SWF, maybe the problem comes from there, can't understand why it wouldn't work as we're doing things in the same way.

Comment: Oh, wait: you add the listener to the loader! This is different than what I do!

Comment: Ben, I don't want to bore you anymore... but it is not working... Anyway it seems you don't load inside a MovieClip (correct me if I'm wrong) but you do what you could once do with loadMovieNum. This is what I do: var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader(); var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("SWFToLoad.swf"); swfLoader.load(bgURL); swfLoader.addEventListener(QuestionAnsweredEvent.QUESTION_ANSWERED,onAnswer); swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete); classContainer_mc.addChild(swfLoader);

Comment: BEN! I found something really strange! It works ONLY if in the child SWF I've a button: when I press that button I can dispatch events. BUT if I dispatch events in the body of the constructor of the document class of the child swf it does not work... Well, the button press is very useful, anyway.

Comment: Ah I'm really sorry, that makes sense, I should have mentioned this: In any SWFs ill be using as a child I have an event listener in the constructor for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE that triggers a function called init(). This is where I do any dispatches to the parent. This makes sure the child SWF has loaded and been added to the parent.

Comment: Wow, I must try this too. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!